# PayPAL sdk error, PPConnectionException timed out

Tags: php, paypal

I am on VPS and I have never faced this issue before. Now today when I tried to use our paypal api I get the following error.

> exception 'PPConnectionException' with message 'Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received' in paypal-sdk-core-php-016a8e4/lib/PPHttpConnection.php:91

Sever Sepcs:

- PHP 5.6
- APACHE
- Our Website is on https

Open SSL:

openssl:

```
  Installed: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.7
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.16
  Version table:
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.16 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.7 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
```

TLS:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
```